# Kafka Protobuf: C++ serialization to java

Tags: java, c++, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, kafka-consumer-api

I've developed a couple of C++ apps that produce and consume Kafka messages (using cppkafka) embedding Protobuf3 messages. Both work fine. The producer's relevant code is:

```
std::string kafkaString;
cppkafka::MessageBuilder *builder;
...
solidList->SerializeToString(&kafkaString);
builder->payload(kafkaString);
```

Protobuf objects are serialized to string and inserted as Kafka payload. Everything works fine up to this point. Now, I'm trying to develop a consumer for that in Java. The relevant code should be:

```
KafkaConsumer<Long, String> consumer=new KafkaConsumer<Long, String>(properties);
....
ConsumerRecords<Long, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
  for (ConsumerRecord<Long, String> record : records) {
    SolidList solidList = SolidList.parseFrom(record.value());
    ...
```

but that fails at compile time: parseFrom complains: **The method parseFrom(ByteBuffer) in the type Solidlist.SolidList is not applicable for the arguments (String)**. So, I try using a ByteBuffer:

```
KafkaConsumer<Long, ByteBuffer> consumer=new KafkaConsumer<Long, ByteBuffer>(properties);
....
ConsumerRecords<Long, ByteBuffer> records = consumer.poll(100);
  for (ConsumerRecord<Long, ByteBuffer> record : records) {
    SolidList solidList = SolidList.parseFrom(record.value());
    ...
```

Now, the error is on execution time, still on parseFrom(): **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.nio.ByteBuffer**. I know it is a java.lang.String!!! So, I get back to the original, and try using it as a byte array:

```
    SolidList solidList = SolidList.parseFrom(record.value().getBytes());
```

Now, the error is on execution time: **Exception in thread "main" com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException$InvalidWireTypeException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.**.

The protobuf documentation states for the C++ serialization: *bool SerializeToString(string* output) const;: serializes the message and stores the bytes in the given string. **Note that the bytes are binary, not text**; we only use the string class as a convenient container.*

TL;DR: In consequence, how should I interpret the protobuf C++ "binary bytes" in Java?

This seems related (it is the opposite) but doesn't help: [Protobuf Java To C++ Serialization [Binary]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509208/protobuf-java-to-c-serialization-binary)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am new to C++ looking for an example to test protobuf serialization using Kafka C++ library.  Would it be possible for you to share your sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing a [Deserializer](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html) and pass it to [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) constructor as value deserializer. It could look like this:

```
class SolidListDeserializer implements Deserializer<SolidList> {
  public SolidList deserialize(final String topic, byte[] data) {
    return SolidList.parseFrom(data);
  }
  ...
}

...

KafkaConsumer<Long, SolidList> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props, new LongDeserializer(), new SolidListDeserializer())
```

Comment: Great! it works! (the deserializer is required, my mistake on a previous comment); thanks, that made the trick. Peace. – RodolfoAP 9 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

You can read kafka as `ConsumerRecords<Long, String>`. And then `SolidList.parseFrom(ByteBuffer.wrap(record.value().getBytes("UTF-8")));`

Comment: I think I've already tried that: it gives **Exception in thread "main" com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).**